# Error con Fracciones Irreducibles

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa que al recibir un número con decimales, lo lleve a una fracción simplificada. Hice algunas pruebas y lo hace bien, pero cuando ingreso 0.24 me da un valor muy alto.

```
int main(){

    float n;
    int aux;
    float dec = 1.0;
    int c = 0;

    cin >> n; cin.ignore();

    while(dec != 0){

        n = n*10.0;
        aux = n;
        dec = n - aux;
        c++;        
    }

    int den = pow(10, c);

    //Simplificando

    while(aux%2==0 && den%2==0){
        aux = aux / 2;
        den = den / 2;
    }

    while(aux%5==0 && den%5==0){
        aux = aux / 5;
        den = den / 5;
    }

    cout << aux << "/" << den << endl;

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué recibes y qué esperabas recibir?

Comment: Hola @Paula_plus_plus. El programa recibe un número con decimales y lo debe llevar a una fracción simplificada. Hasta ahora, para las pruebas que he hecho lo hace bien pero cuando introduzco 0.24 en vez de recibir 6/25 arroja 11999999/50000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola @StellaW creo que tengo la solucion a tu problema...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

char a[100];
char nu[100];

int MCD(int A, int B) {
    while (A > 0 && B > 0)
        if (A > B)
            A = A % B;
        else
            B = B % A;
    return A + B;
}

int main() {


    cin.getline(a, 100);

    int cd = 0;

    int pos = 0;

    for (auto x : a)
    {
        if (x != '.')
            pos++;
        else
            break;
    }

    //este for busca la potencia a elevar
    for (int i = pos + 1; i < strlen(a); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(a[i]))
            cd++;
    }

    //copia el numerador de la entrada original sin el punto
    for (int i = 0, aux = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)
        if (isdigit(a[i]))
            nu[aux++] = a[i];

    double num, den;

    //comparamos si ambas cadenas son iguales, contando el 0 como numero...pues esta a la derecha, no como digito significativo sino como digito
    if (strlen(a) == strlen(nu) + 1) 
    {
        num = atoi(nu);
        den = pow(10, cd);
    }
    //en caso de que sean iguales qiere decir que no existe el flotante, el numerador sera el propio array nu o a
    else if (strlen(a) == strlen(nu)) 
    {
        num = atoi(nu);
        den = 1;
    }


    while (MCD(num, den) != 1)
    {
        int mcd = MCD(num, den);
        num /= mcd;
        den /= mcd;
    }

    if (den == 1)
        cout << num;
    else
        cout << num << "/" << den;

    return 0;
}
```

Ahora te voy a dar la explicacion de xq el resultado descabellado...que me ocurrio tambien...
El problema es que la funcion pow devuelve un double y tu guardas en den ese valor que es int...
No se decirte el porque en vez de dar 100 da 99 disuclpame desconozco el porque pero me pasa a veces y lo que hago es cambiarlo a double...
Y otra cosa para simplifacar una fraccion recuerda siempre utilizar el algoritmo de euclides de MCD...Salu2 ;)

Comment: Gracias! no conocía ese algoritmo. Por curiosidad estuve poniendo algunas banderas dentro del primer While y creo que el error se genera allí. Al parecer cuando guardo el valor de n en aux se guarda un número menor al que tiene n. Esto solo me pasa con el 0.24. De resto con las pruebas que he hecho (tampoco han sido muchas xD) lo hace bien. ¿Sabes que podrá ser?

Comment: Voy a ponerme en eso este fin de semana tb tngo esa duda pero estaba muy ocupado x eso te hice el código... Por cierto si fueras tan amable y el código te sirvió de ayuda marcalo como una respuesta válida a tu pregunta gracias

Comment: Sí, eso hice. Pero como soy nueva me dice que la puntuación se registra pero no cambia publicamente :(

Comment: Tienes que darle a la palomita que aparece abajo voto negativo :)

Comment: Listo, gracias ^-^

Comment: un placer ayudar siempre...